# Ionic Capacitor running in android - CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to run my capacitor app in android,
running through android studio - the app opens and says:

```
"Webpage not available - the webpage at "http://localhost:8100" could not be loaded because of ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
```

and it's quite obvious that I can't access my app by navigating to `http://localhost:8100` from my android device (only from the computer which is connected with wires), so I wonder how it should work..

Any idea?

Answer (score 18):

OK so I just checked the `ionic capacitor run` [command options docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-run) and saw this:

```
--external
Description 
Host dev server on all network interfaces (i.e. --host=0.0.0.0)
```

Tried it... and it works.

running my app with:

`ionic capacitor run android -l --external` worked on the same wi-fi

Comment: Lol, My phone and laptop are on the same LAN, running it with external tag, and it still isn't working. It's showing ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. Is it an issue with Capacitor or my LAN ?

Comment: "ionic capacitor run android -l --external" is the answer. That's how I got it working on iOS, than for some reason, Ionic Official Docs had the same step for Android with a slightly different other command, which only worked the 1st time: "ionic capacitor run android -l --host=YOUR_IP_ADDRESS"

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me was using the external URL provided by ionic to call my end-point instead of `localhost`

When I want to test on the emulator/device, I ran `ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external`

and then the console show me this [image]

so to call to my endpoint I used to do `http://localhost:8080/api`, instead, I must do `http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/api`

Answer (score 1):

Just another answer for someone who may encounter the problem the way I faced it:

On my computer (Windows 10) the issue was that a connection from the phone to my computer was not allowed. My network connection was configured with a guest/public profile and it did not have network detection on.
I fixed this by:

1. navigating to Start -> Settings -> Network and internet -> Wi-Fi tab ->Manage know networks -> select the network you are connected to -> click properties -> set network profile to private
2. navigating to control panel ->Network and internet -> network center -> advanced settings for sharing (on the left) -> check that network detection is on for your selected profile (private)

ionic cap run android -l --external displays the app on the phone now